# Objects passed by reference?

Tags: objective-c, oop, object

If I have an object 'Hotel' which has a few set properties and I pass it to another object which populates more of its properties and then releases it will the first class see these values?

Comment: This is not pass-by-reference. Pass-by-reference means (example in C++) `void f(int& arg) {arg = 0;} int x = 5; f(x);` results in `x = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work. But the object isn't passed by reference; rather, you're passing a *pointer* to the object, which means the caller and the callee both have pointers to the same object; thus, if you use a mutator to modify the object's properties, both the caller and the callee will see the changes.